# angularjs ng-table/ng-repeat rows not loading

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

I am trying to follow the tutorial [Here](http://ng-table.com/#/) on using ng-Table. If I download the whole example from Git then it loads fine but trying to follow even the simplest example myself then the Column headers and filters load but there are no rows? If I add another row in the HTML manually it does appear so the issue seems to either be with the data binding or the ng-repeat. There are no errors showing in the console.

[image]

Example Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" ; href="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@4.0.0/bundles/ng-table.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@4.0.0/bundles/ng-table.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
            <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
                <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
                    {{user.name}}
                </td>
                <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
                    {{user.age}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>


    <script>
        var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngTable"]);

        app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, NgTableParams) {
            var self = this;
            var data = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 } /*,*/];
            self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: data });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified your controller reference.

Change the code to `<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">` and it will work as you expect it.

Working example: http://codepen.io/DeividasK/pen/qrWqey?editors=1010

Comment: Glad to hear. Make sure to mark the question as answered so that others would save time ;)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign your object in scope

try this below code instead of your code

```
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, NgTableParams) {
        var self = this;
         self.data  = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 } /*,*/];
        self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset:  self.data });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have swapped your code in but the result is the same.

Comment: @JoshuaCook oops! also you need change this line ` ng-table="vm.tableParams"` to ` ng-table="tableParams"`

Comment: Hi, i have tried this but odly does not work? However changing 'ng-controller="MyCtrl"' to 'ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm"' works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

This is ng table, the problem is you are using the controller as vm, just remove the vm or put controller as vm and it's work.

```
 <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
            <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
                <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
                    {{user.name}}
                </td>
                <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
                    {{user.age}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```